# Display a div only if another div has content (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 div :

- a container (typing-container)
- a div that displays an animation of someone writing* (typing-indicator)
- a div that shows the usernames of people writing (typing-names)

Here's a part of the code of the component :

```
<div
  className="typing-container"
>
  <div
    className="typing-indicator"
  >
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div
    id="typing-names"
  ></div>
</div>
```

**I want to display the typing-indicator div only if typing-names div has content**

Something like this, but I don't know how to put it in React (with Hooks),

```
if (document.getElementByid("typing-names").innerHTML !== "") {
  document.getElementsByClassName("typing-indicator")[0].style.display = "none";
} else {
  document.getElementsByClassName("typing-indicator")[0].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

**But how can I do this in React ? And please no jQuery !**

*Link of animation if you want to see it : [https://www.google.com/search?q=message+typing+css&rlz=1C1CHBD_frFR755FR755&sxsrf=ACYBGNTAK7JVbTZYCL53oXza1zM4c9isXw:1574531740368&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsvsno84DmAhWrx4UKHT1LCPQQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1920&bih=937#imgrc=Bd1G1Ka8LZ3JKM:](https://www.google.com/search?q=message%20typing%20css&rlz=1C1CHBD_frFR755FR755&sxsrf=ACYBGNTAK7JVbTZYCL53oXza1zM4c9isXw:1574531740368&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsvsno84DmAhWrx4UKHT1LCPQQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1920&bih=937#imgrc=Bd1G1Ka8LZ3JKM:)

Comment: just check if the data you are going to display in typing-names exists then display the typing indicator. ```{ dataExistsInTypingNames && <div
    className="typing-indicator"
  >
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div> }```

Comment: Where does `typing-names`'s content come from?

Comment: Yeah, if you know the `typing-name`'s content, you can directly add a `this.setState({showIndicator: true })` there. And while rendering you can do something what @JuniusL. is suggesting.

Comment: @Henry Woody it comes from the server of the app, I'm using socket.io to do the live chat

Comment: @Versifiction but how does `typing-name` get that content (where in your React app is this information stored)?